# Not able to import sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, nltk

Not able to import sklearn. The first time when I import sklearn it shows me following :-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .format_stack import format_outer_frames
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/format_stack.py", line 35, in <module>
    generate_tokens = tokenize.tokenize
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tokenize'
```

Then, I reimport it (immediately after first try) it shows me this :-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
```

I reinstall the sklearn by performing below mentioned steps but still the problem remains the same.

Steps:-

```
pip uninstall sklearn
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install sklearn
```

On the other side, I don't know how it is related to this nltk library since it produces the same error when I tried `import nltk`. The error in case of nltk import is shown below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.parse import ParserI
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/transitionparser.py", line 21, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .format_stack import format_outer_frames
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/format_stack.py", line 35, in <module>
    generate_tokens = tokenize.tokenize
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tokenize'
```

If I reimport nltk immediately after first import just like what is did with sklearn it shows me this :-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.util import ChunkScore
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/util.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.tag.mapping import map_tag
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from nltk.tag.sequential    import (SequentialBackoffTagger, ContextTagger,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 25, in <module>
    from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
    from nltk.classify.megam import config_megam, call_megam
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/megam.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk import compat
ImportError: cannot import name compat
```

Versions :-

```
Platform: Linux-4.15.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
Sys: 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
     [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Scipy: 0.17.0
Numpy: 1.14.5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tried this `nltk.download('all')`?

Comment: @VanPeer for this i have to first `import nltk` , but as i told it gave me the above mentioned error. Although I have tried the command line solution for this but still the problem remains.